# Parse duplicate elements with the same name into NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, xcode4.5

All of the elements are stored in NSStrings except dog which is stored in an NSArray. I want all the dog entries to be added to the NSArray. Right now  only one dog value is being added to the array. How can I add all the dog values to the NSArray?

```
<root>
         <element>
                <person>Jim<person/> 
                <age>21<age/>
                <dog>Labrador<dog/>
                <dog>Beagle<dog/>
                <dog>Yorkshire Terrier<dog/>
         <element/>
         <element>
                <person>Jill<person/> 
                <age>50<age/>
                <dog>Boxer<dog/>
                <dog>Pug<dog/>
                <dog>Labrador<dog/>
                <dog>Beagle<dog/>
                <dog>Yorkshire Terrier<dog/>
         <element/>
     </root>


 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {
            //Initialize the array.
            appDelegate.entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]) {

            //Initialize the entry.
            anEntry = [[Entry alloc] init];

            //Extract the attribute here.
            anEntry.entryID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

            NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", anEntry.entryID);
        }

        NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

        if(!currentElementValue) 
            currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
        else
            [currentElementValue appendString:string];

        NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"])
            return;


        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]) {
            [appDelegate.entries addObject:anEntry];

            anEntry = nil;
        }
        else
            [anEntry setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this is that there are multiple values for the key dog.
So if you say:

```
[anEntry setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

Then that key (elementName) may already contain a value.You are using well the parser, you have understood how it works, the only thing is that you have to consider all the tags, not only element and root.In that if-then.else you must also consider the case that the tag is dog:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"])
        return;


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]) {
        [appDelegate.entries addObject:anEntry];

        anEntry = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString: @"dog"])
    {
        [anEntry.dogs addObject: currentElementValue];
    }
    else
        [anEntry setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

This case your entry class should have a property named dogs which is a NSMutableArray, readable.